# Regular expressions match first number next to a given character

Tags: php, regex

how can I match a the first number next to a % character ?

```
<?php
$string = 'Get 30% off when you spend over £100 on electronics';

 if(strpos($string,'% off') !== false) {
        $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9%]/", '', $string);
        return $number;
 }
```

this returns 30%100

any help would be great thanks in advance.

Comment: you trying to match the 30 with what? I see your IF statement if it is not equal to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will match (and capture) all digits preceding a '%' sign:

```
'/(\d+)%/'
```

You can try something like this:

```
$string = 'Get 30% off when you spend over £100 on electronics';
preg_match('/(\d+)%/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Do let us know if your requirements are more complex.

Comment: this would match 1000000000000% which isn't a valid percentage

Comment: The OP did not specify that there was any range, he just asked for numbers before a '%' sign -- hence my comment in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
\d{1,3}%
```

Explained:

```
\d{1,3} match a digit [0-9]
    Quantifier: {1,3} Between 1 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
% matches the character % literally
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick :)

```
if(strpos($string,'%') !== false) {
        $regex_percent = "/((\d{1,5})(?:%))/";
        preg_match($regex_percent, $string, $matches_off);
        $number = $matches_off[2];

        return $number;
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain it's always going to be an integer before the `%`?  You're never going to have 20.5% for example?